# When writing code for a specific Operating System, what are the tradeoffs between standard library calls vs all OS API calls?

Tags: c++, api, standard-library

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using standard library calls vs the OS's API calls when programming something you know will be targeted for one operating system?

For example, in C++ I'm programming specifically for Windows, so should I do this

```
memcpy(studentCopy, student, sizeof(Student));
```

Or stick to Windows API calls, as such:

```
CopyMemory(studentCopy, student, sizeof(Student));
```

I'm unsure of which convention is better and have been unable to find anything from searches. Is it simply preference?

Edit: The student thing was just an example of using different libraries, not asking about that specifically, it was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Yes it's always a good practice to prefer STL over OS specific API.

Comment: As (the class or struct?) Student, its base classes, or their data members might have specific assignment operators, I would prefer: studentCopy = student;

Comment: Depends if an OS specific call provides more functionality. For example Windows has calls to support files greater than 4 GB, the "...ex" versions of some calls: [file management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx) . The [multimedia timer functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609(v=vs.85).aspx) may be useful.

Comment: @40two: What does STL have to do with this?

Comment: Why all the closing requests? It's a good question

Comment: @BenVoigt excuse me please I meant It's always a good practice to prefer standard routines over OS API specif ones :)

Comment: @icepack: Well, it was opinion-based, really.  I hope replacing "which is better?" by "what are the tradeoffs?" will rescue it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve, really.

Using Windows API calls will make your code unportable.

Also, compilers often "understand" things like `memcpy`, `strcpy`, and so on, and can make clever optimisations based on what they really do (e.g. use SSE instructions to copy 32 bytes with 4 instructions, instead of passing three values to a function and performing the copy in that function [which would have to check things like alignment and size and then determine how to actually make the copy].

I personally would only use Windows API calls if they are "unavoidable" - that is, there is no other easy way to achieve the desired result. If there is a C/C++ standard functionality, then use that.

Of course, in an object oriented design, you probably don't want to use `memcpy` to copy variables, since they may not be of the same class and/or non-trivial constructor/destructors, so

```
studentCopy = student;
```

would be my preferred solution, regardless of the system.

Comment: What do you mean by compilers that "understand" memcpy, strcpy, and so on?.. They understand it via inclusion of the relevant headers, like any other function

Comment: It would be foolish to think that msvc++ optimizes memcpy better than CopyMemory.

Comment: @zneak: Only because `#define CopyMemory memcpy` in windows.h  (There really is a `CopyMemory` function exported from the system DLLs, but the windows headers don't contain a prototype for it)

Comment: @zneak: I have no idea, as the source code is "closed", and I'm currently in the process of converting my last Windows machine to Linux (and can't be bothered to install a compiler just to possibly prove a point). I know gcc and clang both have special recognition of common library functions. [Ben Voigt just answered this particular case - it's the same thing, so there's no benefit in using CopyMemory]

Comment: @BenVoigt, I can find an export for memcpy too. Which is defined to which is anecdotal and made possible because MS didn't have to choose between the two. I believe that it is baseless and misleading to say that standard functions will outperform platform functions (though they could very well outperform equivalent user functions). A standard library that beats the platform it is hosted on speaks of a very weak platform. On Linux (to avoid ideology getting in the way), is fread faster or even just equally as fast as read?

Comment: There are many good reasons to use portable APIs, but the optimization one makes a very weak case in my opinion.

Comment: @zneak: `memcpy` is fast because it's a compiler intrinsic -- the DLL export is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the situation.

Standard library advantage is in the portability of the code. 
OS API advantage is in possibly better/more suitable implementation of the desired functionality for the specific OS/environment. This is in particular common in the lower level programming, such as interfacing HW or writing in kernel. E.g., in Windows kernel standard library isn't officially supported (although some functionality will work).

Another reason to consider when choosing APIs is compliance to various SW certifications (if they're needed) that might require/forbid certain APIs.

And last but not least reason is consistency of the code for further maintenance and readability - strive towards not mixing APIs of different kind.

Answer (score 1):

Using only OS libraries can result in a lower footprint -- if you successfully eliminate every single reference to the C++ standard library, you can avoid linking with it at all.

Usually this isn't worth the effort, but for some scenarios (e.g. a diagnostic tool to check whether the C++ runtime DLLs are present on the system) it can be very useful.

(As icepack mentions, this only applies to using functions implemented in OS files, be careful to avoid extra libraries provided with the OS vendor but requiring separate redistribution, if you want to keep as low a footprint as possible)

Comment: Same reasoning can be applied against linking with specific OS libraries

Comment: @icepack: Huh?  The OS libraries are already on the system; they aren't part of your application footprint.

Comment: Some of the OS libraries come in the form of static library and won't be available without static linkage

Comment: @icepack: I think you may be discussing a different OS than the question (although I think generic answers are also interesting)

Comment: Actually, it's very relevant to Windows. I come across this all the time in Windows kernel, where certain driver frameworks are defined in static libraries. Admittedly, it's probably less common for user space code but the question scope is wider.

Comment: @icepack: But those libraries are part of a framework (SDK), not part of the OS.

Comment: Ok, I included the OS SDKs in the scope of OS itself but I suppose your definition is more precise.